# Multiple field include exlude with python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql

My api needs to be something like this:

```
api/search_fields=country_name,region,city,pincode,dma&exclude=false,true,true,false&country_name=india,pakistan&region=tamil nadu,jammu kashmir,&city=ahmedabad&pincode=112&dma=1
```

Means if country_name is excluded their correspoding region,city,pincode,dma will not come in result.Same way if region is exluded city,pincode,dma will not come in results of which all countries are excluded and which all regions are excluded.

How can i write mysql template in python for all these.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is very wide, I will try to answer.

The general idea is checking what the user has specified in the request and then hide absent columns in the output. We call it a view logic. You can take care of it in Controller or in Template directly.

Probably, it does not help you too much, but I cannot answer another way so broad question.